# Problems in communication between parent and child - Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to act on a parent component based on a child output, but i'm getting

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf:
>   [object Object]'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.

Here is my code:

Parent Component html

```
<div *ngIf="hasErrors">!</div>
<app-error [valuesForErrors]="..." (hasErrors)="setHasErrors($event)"></app-error>
```

Parent Component ts (section)

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
    hasErrors = false;
    ...
    setHasErrors(hasErrors) {
        this.hasErrors = hasErrors;
    }
```

I've seen some solutions with Subject and Observable from rxjs, but they didn't work on my project :/

Edit

A friend helped gave me another solution, just make the emitter asynchronous with a true on the declaration:

Child Component ts

```
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() valuesForErrors: any;
    @Output() hasErrors: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(true);
    ...
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.calculateErrors()
    }

    calculateErrors() {
        let errors = ... some logic that returns a boolean;
        this.hasErrors.emit(errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of "errors" you are emitting from child function calculateErrors?

Comment: a boolean calculated based on valuesForErrors

Comment: The approach you're using here – where a child component calculates state (`hasErrors`) and then propagates it up to the parent component – seems like a violation of the "unidirectional data flow" principle.

It might simplify things in the long run if you move the error calculation into the topmost point of the component hierarchy where it is used (i.e. `ParentComponent`), and then make the parent provide it to the child as an input binding. This will probably fix the error too.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same, but sadly I can't change the place where the error is calculated :/, mostly because this ErrorComponent is going to be used by multiple different Components.

Comment: Sometimes it's to do with the [template hierarchy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18004#issuecomment-328806479) - wrap `<div *ngIf="hasErrors">!</div>` in a `<div *ngIf="true">!</div>` if this is the case

Comment: @AndrewAllen you are a crazy guy, this worked like a charm, and I still don't understand why... thank you very much. Please, put it as an Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you ever wondered if the world is just out to get you?

Well, sometimes it's true. You've encountered one of the nastiest behaviours that angular throws.

Normally, like 95% of the time, `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is basically angular telling you that you don't understand the basics of lifecycle detection: *ngOnChanges* vs *ngOnInit* vs *ngAfterViewInit*. But occasionally it's because of the nesting and template hierarchy and the order checks are made in your template.

Take the following which throws the error:

```
<form [name]="formName"
      [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div *ngIf="true">
    <input formControlName="name"
           required
           placeholder="Please enter you name">
  </div>
</form>
<div *ngIf="formGroup.valid">
  Name is required.
</div>
```

The reason for the error being thrown is that change detection evaluates the *ngIf of the error div first before it evaluates the input's validity, as the input is one level lower in terms of template hierarchy.

A workaround is to bring the error div onto the same level as the input by adding just another `<div *ngIf="true"></div>` around it (as mentioned above).

[Not all heros wear capes, some leave Github comments](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18004#issuecomment-328806479)

Comment: I attempted  to do the same, but in the html code using <div *ngIf="pageLoaded ? hasErrors : false"></div> and didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: @DanielQuicazán I've updated the stackblitz with this...I'll need to think about it and come back to you.

Comment: Ok, but, in my code, the validation is made by a child component. I already implemented the first solution, adding a <ng-container *ngIf="true"> instead of the div, but the other solution you propose sounds interesting

Comment: @DanielQuicazán I've undone my update - there's no reliable way to use pageLoaded unless you know for certain what `formGroup.valid` will be on initialisation

Answer (score 1):

Modify parent component like this:

`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }


setHasErrors(hasErrors) {
    this.hasErrors = hasErrors;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I found that solution, but they told me that you shouldn't change the Angular life cycle.

Comment: Then we have to find what is causing this issue, it will be helpful if you share your code in stackbiltz

Comment: I found that is caused because of the order in which Angular renders the components, so, when you change the value on hasErrors in the parent component, it already calculated if it had to render or not the div